# PHP 5+ stream wrappers with the underlying WordPress File API?

Tags: php

I followed the gsoc project last year from Jon Stacey with great interest only to find out that this project was just the 'base' for a working solution.

http://gsoc2010.wordpress.com/tag/stream-wrappers/

Sadly, it seems the project is not part of gsoc this year so the project is somewhat orphaned right now.

Question:
Is anyone aware of any completed php stream wrapper for wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

I've been pointed at the GSoC project, but I haven't explored its finer points, yet. (Looks like that will take a decent chunk of time.) Practically speaking, I tried to use WordPress with stream wrappers, and I immediately found that `wp_mkdir_p()` and the GD functions `imagejpeg()`, `imagegif()` and `imagepng()` were incompatible.

I've submitted [a patch to help the WordPress media uploader better support stream wrappers](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18543).

Obviously, this is not as holistic an approach as the GSoC project aims to be, but these are the changes I had to make to store media using a registered stream wrapper.